# jquery load function for small preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

```
     <strong>Preview:</strong> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<div id=\"preview\"></div>
```

In the following div i need to show  a very small preview of a page.In order to do that what should be the css set to,
When i use the following code below,the preview is very big.I need to show the preview with the size of the videos on you tube(as In suggestions tab)

```
var url="/tools/display/" + param;
$('#preview').css({"width" : "200px" , "height" : "10px" , "background-color" : "Black" , "position" : "fixed","display" : "inline" });
$("#preview").load(url);
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the CSS property `overflow: auto` or `overflow: scroll` or `overflow: hidden`.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Scale. Give that a try. I think you are looking to scale the entire HTML doc into a small DIV element?

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Scale

Answer (score 0):

in general those previews are images that are generated server side.

If you don't want to implement your own server side logic, you could try a service like:
http://www.websnapr.com/

Have a look [at this page](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/content/thumbnail) to see an example of how to use websnapr.com with jQuery